# How to solve the problem with paragraph justification in LaTeX

Tags: alignment

I have met with a problem with the justification of a paragraph in LaTeX. See the image below.

[image]

The MWE LaTeX code is as below:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}%
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{geometry}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\geometry{margin=1in,top=1.25in,bottom=1.25in}
\begin{document}
\begin{corollary}   \label{16}\ Suppose in a sequence of structures
    $\{(\mathfrak{M}_{n},\phi_n)\colon \mathfrak{M}_{n}
    \models\phi_{n}\land n<\omega\}$ of a $\aleph_{0}$-categorical theory
    $T$, there are finitely many homogeneous subsequences of structures
    $\{(\mathfrak{M}_{n_i}, \phi_{n_i}) \colon \mathfrak{M}_{n_i}
    \models\phi_{n_i}\land n_i<\omega\}$. Then there is a unique formula
    $\widetilde{\phi_i}$ in $\mathcal{L}$ (up to equivalence) and a unique
    countable atomic structure $\widetilde{\mathfrak{M_i}}$ (up to
    isomorphism) for each $\{(\mathfrak{M}_{n_i},\phi_{n_i})\}$ such that
    $\widetilde{\mathfrak{M_i}}\models\widetilde{\phi_i}$. In addition,
    there is a $N_i\in\omega$ such that
    $\,\widetilde{\phi_i}\,=\underset{N_i<n_i<\omega}
    {\displaystyle\bigwedge}{\phi}_{n_i}$ which is the complete formula of
    $\widetilde{\mathfrak{M_i}}$. 
\end{corollary}
\end{document}
```

The problem happens inside `{}`. So the question is how to break the curly bracket to make alignment work. Thanks.

Comment: PLease extend your code fragment to MWE, which we can test as it is. A cure fir right alignment is rewording your corollary. Maybe with some inline math (which seem to protrude right text border) change to display one.

Comment: The math expression that is having trouble breaking is quite long, and there isn't really a good place to break it.  A skilled copyeditor would most likely pull the whole thing out and display it, unnumbered.  You can do this by wrapping it in `\[ ... \]`, including the period at the end.

Comment: I changed to MWE latex code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for posting a compilable MWE, as it greatly simplifies the search for a solution of your formatting objective, which is how to fix a bad line-break situation that involves an inline math object.

- The first corollary in the following screenshot replicates the OP's screenshot.
- Before providing a solution for the OP's stated objective, it's worth fixing a few minor things about the paragraph in question. For instance, it's worth replacing

  ```
   $\,\widetilde{\phi_i}\,=\underset{N_i<n_i<\omega}
   {\displaystyle\bigwedge}{\phi}_{n_i}$
  ```

  with

  ```
   $\widetilde{\phi}_i=
   \smashoperator{\bigwedge_{N_i<n_i<\omega}} \phi_{n_i}$
  ```

  in order to avoid creating a large and unsightly visual gap around the "big wedge" symbol in the final line of the corollary. (The macro `\smashoperator` is provided by the [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package, which is a superset of the [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package.) Also, since `\mathfrak` operates only on uppercase letters, it's better to write `\mathfrak{M}_i` rather than `\mathfrak{M_i}`. See the second corollary below for the result of fixing these preliminary issues.
- As @barbarabeeton has already pointed out in a comment, there are two types of solutions to the formatting issue the OP has encountered. The first is to manually insert a directive -- specifically, the `\allowbreak` directive -- somewhere in the problematic inline math formula to indicate where a line break should occur. Here, it looks like a good idea to allow a line break after `\colon`. See the third corollary below.
- The second solution is to switch to a displayed formula; see the fourth corollary below. I think that this is by far the best solution for most such use cases.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools} % 'mathtools' is a superset of 'amsmath'
%\usepackage{amsfonts} % 'amsfonts' is loaded automatically by 'amssymb'

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=1in,vmargin=1.25in}
% '{margin=1in,top=1.25in,bottom=1.25in}' isn't unambiguous

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{2}
\setcounter{theorem}{5} % just for this example

\begin{corollary}   \label{16}
\ Suppose in a sequence of structures
$\{(\mathfrak{M}_{n},\phi_n)\colon 
\mathfrak{M}_{n} \models\phi_{n}\land n<\omega\}$ 
of a $\aleph_{0}$-categorical theory $T$, there are 
finitely many homogeneous subsequences of structures
$\{(\mathfrak{M}_{n_i}, \phi_{n_i}) \colon 
\mathfrak{M}_{n_i} \models\phi_{n_i}\land n_i<\omega\}$. 
Then there is a unique formula
$\widetilde{\phi_i}$ in $\mathcal{L}$ (up to 
equivalence) and a unique countable atomic structure 
$\widetilde{\mathfrak{M_i}}$ (up to isomorphism) for each 
$\{(\mathfrak{M}_{n_i},\phi_{n_i})\}$ such that
$\widetilde{\mathfrak{M_i}}\models\widetilde{\phi_i}$. 
In addition, there is a $N_i\in\omega$ such that
$\,\widetilde{\phi_i}\,=\underset{N_i<n_i<\omega}
{\displaystyle\bigwedge}{\phi}_{n_i}$ 
which is the complete formula of
$\widetilde{\mathfrak{M_i}}$. 
\end{corollary}

\begin{corollary}   \label{16a}
Suppose that in a sequence of structures
$\{(\mathfrak{M}_{n},\phi_n)\colon 
\mathfrak{M}_{n} \models\phi_{n}\land n<\omega\}$ 
of an $\aleph_{0}$-categorical theory $T$, there are 
finitely many homogeneous subsequences of structures
$\{(\mathfrak{M}_{n_i}, \phi_{n_i}) \colon 
\mathfrak{M}_{n_i} \models\phi_{n_i}\land n_i<\omega\}$. 
Then there is a unique formula
$\widetilde{\phi}_i$ in $\mathcal{L}$ (up to 
equivalence) and a unique countable atomic structure 
$\widetilde{\mathfrak{M}}_i$ (up to isomorphism) for each 
$\{(\mathfrak{M}_{n_i},\phi_{n_i})\}$ such that
$\widetilde{\mathfrak{M}}_i\models\widetilde{\phi}_i$. 
In addition, there is an $N_i\in\omega$ such that
$\widetilde{\phi}_i=
\smashoperator{\bigwedge_{N_i<n_i<\omega}} \phi_{n_i}$ 
which is the complete formula of
$\widetilde{\mathfrak{M}}_i$. 
\end{corollary}

\begin{corollary}   \label{16b}
Suppose that in a sequence of structures
$\{(\mathfrak{M}_{n},\phi_n)\colon 
\mathfrak{M}_{n} \models\phi_{n}\land n<\omega\}$ 
of an $\aleph_{0}$-categorical theory $T$, there are 
finitely many homogeneous subsequences of structures
$\{(\mathfrak{M}_{n_i}, \phi_{n_i}) \colon \allowbreak % <-- '\allowbreak' is new
\mathfrak{M}_{n_i} \models\phi_{n_i}\land n_i<\omega\}$. 
Then there is a unique formula
$\widetilde{\phi}_i$ in $\mathcal{L}$ (up to 
equivalence) and a unique countable atomic structure 
$\widetilde{\mathfrak{M}}_i$ (up to isomorphism) for each 
$\{(\mathfrak{M}_{n_i},\phi_{n_i})\}$ such that
$\widetilde{\mathfrak{M}}_i\models\widetilde{\phi}_i$. 
In addition, there is an $N_i\in\omega$ such that
$\widetilde{\phi}_i=
\smashoperator{\bigwedge_{N_i<n_i<\omega}} \phi_{n_i}$ 
which is the complete formula of
$\widetilde{\mathfrak{M}}_i$. 
\end{corollary}

\begin{corollary}   \label{16c}
Suppose that in a sequence of structures
$\{(\mathfrak{M}_{n},\phi_n)\colon 
\mathfrak{M}_{n} \models\phi_{n}\land n<\omega\}$ 
of an $\aleph_{0}$-categorical theory $T$, there are 
finitely many homogeneous subsequences of structures
\[
\bigl\{(\mathfrak{M}_{n_i}, \phi_{n_i}) \colon 
\mathfrak{M}_{n_i} \models\phi_{n_i}\land n_i<\omega\bigr\} \,.
\] 
Then there is a unique formula
$\widetilde{\phi}_i$ in $\mathcal{L}$ (up to 
equivalence) and a unique countable atomic structure 
$\widetilde{\mathfrak{M}}_i$ (up to isomorphism) for each 
$\{(\mathfrak{M}_{n_i},\phi_{n_i})\}$ such that
$\widetilde{\mathfrak{M}}_i\models\widetilde{\phi}_i$. 
In addition, there is an $N_i\in\omega$ such that
$\widetilde{\phi}_i=
\smashoperator{\bigwedge_{N_i<n_i<\omega}} \phi_{n_i}$ 
which is the complete formula of
$\widetilde{\mathfrak{M}}_i$. 
\end{corollary}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: @EugeneZhang - You're most welcome.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you should use `\colon` in this case, which is for maps like in `f\colon A\rightarrow B`. In the set-builder notation, the colon is a relation symbol.

You should also use better names, such as `\fM` for `\mathfrak{M}` and `\cL` for `\mathcal{L}`, which makes for simpler input and avoids mistakes such as `\mathfrak{M_i}`, that should be `\mathfrak{M}_i`.

I also used upright parentheses (I don't really like their slantedness in Computer Modern).

Finally, I replaced the ugly realization of `\models` with `\vDash`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}%
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\geometry{margin=1in,top=1.25in,bottom=1.25in}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}

\newcommand{\fM}{\mathfrak{M}}
\newcommand{\cL}{\mathcal{L}}
\newcommand{\wt}{\widetilde}

\renewcommand{\models}{\vDash}

\begin{document}

\begin{corollary}\label{16}
Suppose in a sequence of structures
$\{(\fM_{n},\phi_n): \fM_{n} \models \phi_{n}\land n<\omega\}$
of a  $\aleph_{0}$-categorical theory $T$, there are 
finitely many homogeneous subsequences of structures 
$\{(\fM_{n_i}, \phi_{n_i}) : \fM_{n_i} \models\phi_{n_i}\land n_i<\omega\}$. 
Then there is a unique formula $\wt{\phi_i}$ in $\cL$ 
\textup{(}up to equivalence\textup{)} and a unique countable atomic structure 
$\wt{\fM_i}$ \textup{(}up to isomorphism\textup{)} for each  
$\{(\fM_{n_i},\phi_{n_i})\}$ such that
$\wt{\fM_i}\models\wt{\phi_i}$.
In addition, there is a $N_i\in\omega$ such that
$\wt{\phi_i}\,= \bigwedge_{N_i<n_i<\omega}\phi_{n_i}$ 
which is the complete formula of $\wt{\fM_i}$. 
\end{corollary}

\end{document}
```

The `\underset` in the last big formula is wrong. You *might* use

```
\bigwedge\limits_{N_i<n_i<\omega}\phi_{n_i}
```

for the particular case where the construct is in the last line of the corollary, but inline it's much better to set the limits on the side.

[image]

If you really want to use `\colon` spacing, define your own symbol that allows a line break

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}%
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\geometry{margin=1in,top=1.25in,bottom=1.25in}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}

\newcommand{\fM}{\mathfrak{M}}
\newcommand{\cL}{\mathcal{L}}
\newcommand{\wt}{\widetilde}

\renewcommand{\models}{\vDash}

\newcommand{\suchthat}{\colon\allowbreak}

\begin{document}

\begin{corollary}\label{16}
Suppose in a sequence of structures
$\{(\fM_{n},\phi_n)\suchthat \fM_{n} \models \phi_{n}\land n<\omega\}$
of a  $\aleph_{0}$-categorical theory $T$, there are 
finitely many homogeneous subsequences of structures 
$\{(\fM_{n_i}, \phi_{n_i}) \suchthat \fM_{n_i} \models\phi_{n_i}\land n_i<\omega\}$. 
Then there is a unique formula $\wt{\phi_i}$ in $\cL$ 
\textup{(}up to equivalence\textup{)} and a unique countable atomic structure 
$\wt{\fM_i}$ \textup{(}up to isomorphism\textup{)} for each  
$\{(\fM_{n_i},\phi_{n_i})\}$ such that
$\wt{\fM_i}\models\wt{\phi_i}$.
In addition, there is a $N_i\in\omega$ such that
$\wt{\phi_i}\,= \bigwedge_{N_i<n_i<\omega}\phi_{n_i}$ 
which is the complete formula of $\wt{\fM_i}$. 
\end{corollary}

\end{document}
```

[image]